# Android: How do I remove an item from a gridview, having the remaing items shuffle into place

Tags: android, gridview, removechild

**BACKGROUND:**
I have a grid of 36 buttons, lets say a 6 rows & 6 columns numbered 1 to 36, displayed 2 rows at a time via a GridView and custom Adapter

The grid displays fine, and all of the scrolling works properly.

**QUESTION:**
I want to be able to click on an item, have it removed from the grid and the remain items shuffle up into place.  Currently I am able to disable the item disabled, set its visibility to INVISIBLE or GONE, but none of these will actually remove it from the display.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, you need to remove the corresponding object from the data set of the underlying adapter and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This isn't going to provide you with an animation, though, if that was part of this question.

It may be interesting to try a [tween animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween) for the item in question and then finally remove it from your adapter at the end. I'm not well-versed in animation, so I'm not sure how well this will work in an `AdapterView`.

Comment: I may be removing multiple items at a time, think dragging your finger across some items. Will I cause performance problems if I call notifyDataSetChanged() multiple times, or should I try and cache the changes and only call once

Comment: You should probably make all of your changes and then notify, if possible. I don't think it's a big deal though, because notifyDataSetChanged() will not cause the ListView to perform an inordinate amount of work immediately

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to update the adapter, and then call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) to force the grid view to be updated.