# How to delete row item from adapterview in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I have an gridview . The adapter of the gridview is as follows :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] mobileValues;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context,int resource, String[] mobileValues) {
        super(context, resource, mobileValues);
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);

            // set value into textview
            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

            // set image based on selected text
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            String mobile = mobileValues[position];

            if (mobile.equals("Windows")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.windows_logo);
            } else if (mobile.equals("iOS")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ios_logo);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Blackberry")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackberry_logo);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo);
            }

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mobileValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mobileValues[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I want to delete an item from the adapter by long click on the gridview . For this I have the following code :

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         imageAdapter.remove(imageAdapter.getItem(position));

        return false;
    }
```

But I get exception . How can I delete an item from adapterview on long click ?

Comment: just remove item from `ArrayList` and then called  `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I have done it . see public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         imageAdapter.remove(imageAdapter.getItem(position));

        return false;
    }

Comment: What is the correct way ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766218/android-remove-gridview-item-from-inside-getview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766218/android-remove-gridview-item-from-inside-getview)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306874/android-how-do-i-remove-an-item-from-a-gridview-having-the-remaing-items-shuff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306874/android-how-do-i-remove-an-item-from-a-gridview-having-the-remaing-items-shuff)

Comment: @osimerpothe: Best is use `List` instead of `Array` if want to perform remove or add operation in Adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using default `remove` method from `ArrayAdapter` for removing item from GridView. create a custom method and remove item from current data-source using position  as:

```
public void removeItem(int pos){
 ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mobileValues));
 arrayList.remove(pos);
 mobileValues = new String[arrayList.size()];
 arrayList.toArray(mobileValues);
 this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now call `removeItem` in `onItemLongClick` method by passing position :

```
imageAdapter.removeItem(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I get exception.

In particular, the exception you are getting is

```
UnsupportedOperationException
```

The super constructor of ArrayAdapter that you are using is

```
public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects) {
        init(context, resource, 0, Arrays.asList(objects));
}
```

as you can notice, it uses `Arrays.asList` to transform your `String[]` in a `List<String>`, and the documentation of `Arrays.asList` states:

> Returns a List of the objects in the specified array. The size of the
>   List cannot be modified, i.e. adding and removing are unsupported, but
>   the elements can be set. Setting an element modifies the underlying
>   array.

To workaround it, when you initialize your dataset, use an `ArrayList<String>`, or another concrete implementation of `List`. If you have already a String[], and you don't want to rewrite it, you can use `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(yourArray))`